# creating dataframe from vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4PYy.jpg)I have the following vectors:

```
bid = c(1,5,10,20,30,40,50)
n = c(31,29,27,25,23,21,19)
yes = c(0,3,6,7,9,13,17)
no = n - yes
```

I have two questions, and I don't find any solutions for them, I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Q1: I want to write R code to create a two-column dataframe **df**. Column 1 has **Bid**,
where each Bid is repeated **n** times; Column 2 has c(rep(1,**yes**),rep(0,**no**) at
each **bid**.

Q2: Then when I have the data frame **df**, I want to write R codes to generate
(from df) vectors bid, n, yes, and no, again.

Comment: Please add example outputs that demonstrate what exactly you are looking for. Also, please add any code you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you tried using the data.frame() function?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you actually want. It is easier if you provide the desired result. Would this fit your Q1:

```
library(tidyverse)
bid = c(1,5,10,20,30,40,50)
n = c(31,29,27,25,23,21,19)
yes = c(0,3,6,7,9,13,17)
no = n - yes

df <- tibble(bid, yes, n, no = n -yes) %>% dplyr::select(- n) %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(yes, no)) %>%  uncount(value) %>% mutate(yesno = ifelse(name == "yes", 1,0)) %>% dplyr::select(-name)


df2 <- df %>% group_by(bid) %>% table() %>%  as.data.frame() %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = bid, names_from = yesno, values_from = Freq) %>% mutate(n = yes + no) %>% rename(no = `0`, yes = `1`)

bid <- df2$bid
n <- df2$n
yes <- df2$yes
```

Comment: Thanks Bloxx, I added a pic of the final dataframe that I want, unfortunately, the first code that you wrote did not result in the dataframe that I wanted.

Comment: check it again. I adjusted to your preferred output.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean for Q2, but for Q1 you could do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pmap_dfr(list(bid, n, yes, no),
         \(V1, V2, V3, V4) tibble(col1 = rep(V1, V2),
                                  col2 = c(rep(1,V3),rep(0,V4))))
#> # A tibble: 175 x 2
#>     col1  col2
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     0
#>  2     1     0
#>  3     1     0
#>  4     1     0
#>  5     1     0
#>  6     1     0
#>  7     1     0
#>  8     1     0
#>  9     1     0
#> 10     1     0
#> # ... with 165 more rows
```

EDIT:
For Q2, you can follow this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- pmap_dfr(list(bid, n, yes, no),
         \(V1, V2, V3, V4) tibble(col1 = rep(V1, V2),
                                  col2 = c(rep(1,V3),rep(0,V4))))

df2 <- df |>
  count(col1, col2) |>
  group_by(col1) |>
  summarise(yes = sum(n[col2==1]),
            n = sum(n))

bid2 <- df2$col1
n2 <- df2$n
yes2 <- df2$yes
no2 <- n2 - yes2

all.equal(c(bid, n, yes, no), c(bid2, n2, yes2, no2))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks AndS, for question 2 I want to write a code to regenerate the vectors from the dataframe. This is a practice to find the reverse code.

Comment: @yora I updated based on your request. Let me know if you have questions.